# How to type list of objects that extend an object with generic types

Tags: typescript

How to type list (object, record, map; anything with key) of objects which are extending another class with generics?

I don't really care about what kind of generics have each object. I just want to type it like *"anything that extend A"*.

```js
// valid abstract class
abstract class A<SOME_TYPE> {
  private something: SOME_TYPE;
  constructor(xxx: SOME_TYPE) {
    console.log(xxx);
  }
}

// valid class
class B extends A<number> {}


// I want a list of objects that extend A
const listOfObjects: Record<string, A<any>> = {
  b: B, // TS2741 error
};
// nor this
const listOfObjects: Record<string, typeof A> = {
  b: B, // Type 'typeof B' is not assignable to type 'typeof A'
};
```

ts v 4.4.4

Comment: Why are you using `Record<string, A<any>>` instead of `A<any>[]` since you want "list" ???

Comment: @bogdanoff I want list of classes not list of instances. Same error comes for array too - it doesn't metter. (et. there is mentioned object and map in question also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) as the type.

```
abstract class A<SOME_TYPE> {
  private something!: SOME_TYPE;

  constructor(arg: string) {}
}

class B extends A<number> {}
class C extends A<number> {}

const listOfObjects: Record<string, new (...args: any) => A<any>> = {
  b: B,
  c: C
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=11&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggHgMoHkBZAUQH0AVATQAViA+BAbwCgEEAHKASwDdgIApgjAB7ALYCIACy4A7AOYBCAFwICJCjWIBuZqyQjZkKAFd4IqAApgUeauNz5ASiYBfZu+YB6Lwj7IuABMkVHRmFDQMACEEAQAPQVlAjBxZEzEQASgGRncI9AQAYViEgSSU7DSMrJzPWENIBADIfAAzfBAAKwF4MFUAJR6LQOwHBQAaBFkBAHcESwA6JZt5PoRgWQBPFwBeBhwNzboGHaZ9EFUo8f1YVUKPbSA)

Comment: This is cool (upvoted) but it doesnt work if you use constructor (updated in question).

Comment: @Jax-p - I See. In that case either use `(...args: any)` if the arguments are not important to you when using the `listOfObjects` type or you can strictly type the parameters.